# how to get value from this JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like this. So, how to get url type basic: https://obs.line-scdn.net/0hLbl4V2I5E01RTTg_zdxsGmMfFC0_IQhTc3lCeS0dDiEgNQxHPX0IK3wfH3R9ehEaPS9ceH0eSg/L100x100\ ?

```
  Image :[ {
        "id": 1,
        "thumbnail": "[{\"url\":\"https://obs.line-scdn.net/0hLbl4V2I5E01RTTg_zdxsGmMfFC0_IQhTc3lCeS0dDiEgNQxHPX0IK3wfH3R9ehEaPS9ceH0eSg/L100x100\",\"width\":100},{\"url\":\"https://obs.line-scdn.net/0hLbl4V2I5E01RTTg_zdxsGmMfFC0_IQhTc3lCeS0dDiEgNQxHPX0IK3wfH3R9ehEaPS9ceH0eSg/L200x200\",\"width\":200},{\"url\":\"https://obs.line-scdn.net/0hLbl4V2I5E01RTTg_zdxsGmMfFC0_IQhTc3lCeS0dDiEgNQxHPX0IK3wfH3R9ehEaPS9ceH0eSg/L500x500\",\"width\":500},{\"url\":\"https://obs.line-scdn.net/0hLbl4V2I5E01RTTg_zdxsGmMfFC0_IQhTc3lCeS0dDiEgNQxHPX0IK3wfH3R9ehEaPS9ceH0eSg/L1000x1000\",\"width\":1000}]",
        "category": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "title"
        },
        "title": "look good",
        "rank": 6,
        "is_new": false,
        "is_pr": false
    }]
```

```
  var{ data } = this.props;
    const image = data ? data.thumbnail : "";
    const convert = image ? image.replace("[","").replace("]", "") : "";
    let img = "";
    if (convert.length !== 0) {
      img = convert ? JSON.parse(convert).url :"";
    }
    console.log(convert)
    const imageStyle = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${img})`,
    };`
```

Comment: Hi Le, can you be more specific? do you want the urls where the thumbnails have L100x100 dimensions from the `thumbnail` array?

Comment: Please add more information to your question like the programming language you are using or a snippet of code you have right now to make it easier for others to answer. Are you asking how to extract the image thumbnail's url property from the JSON?

Comment: You need to parse the `thumbnail` property to make it an array. Looks like you have nested JSON

Answer (score -1):

You need to deploy the web api which will return you this json object,After deploying you will get the URL . so you can fetch this in react component using 
fetch(urlForApi).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>HereIsTheData)